# Is it possible to animate individual draw calls in a CALayer?

Tags: swift, objective-c, calayer

I'm drawing in a single CALayer between 100 and up to 1000 dots (colored circles actually) in a grid, when each dot state changes from hidden to shown and viceversa. So this layer is drawn quite a lot. The reason I went with a single layer and not 1000 layers is because I think performance would be hit with so many layers. Now I want to animate the dissappearance of (maybe multiple) dots over 2 seconds, a fade-off. Is that possible to do for each individual draw call?

Comment: You have not explained what "animate" means for you, so it's difficult to answer specifically. If the animation is a simple fade, yes, it's easy. Except that you also have not explained what "draw" means in a layer. You've shown no code and given no specifics of what you want to do.

Comment: Draw is just draw a colored circle. And by animate I mean fade yes. A simple fadeout of those circles that are in an off state, until invisible.

Comment: So just draw all the circles that you want visible in another layer and fade between layer 1 and layer 2. (However I should also mention that I'm dubious about the value of this entire single-layer approach. It's not how I would do it. I'd use a _view_.)

Comment: The layer is part of a grid view, it's only used to draw all dots. Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try that.

Comment: Consider the phrase "premature optimization". It means: do not waste any effort optimizing something until you can prove by measurement that it _needs_ optimization.

Comment: I know well about it, but having 1000 views is going to impact performance, and that's what layers are for. There are only two options, having 1000 layers or just drawing it all in a single one.

Comment: And do we know for a fact that having 1000 layers is problematic?

Comment: It was an educated guess, but I could be wrong.